# How to best keep the first N elements in Vec and release unused capacity?

Tags: vector, rust, memory-management

I want to keep only the first 2 elements in a `Vec` and release any unused capacity. Here is my current solution:

```
let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; // produced by another function
data.truncate(2);
data.shrink_to_fit();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not use just a slice? Do you actually need to retain the values?

Comment: Yes, since the data is a two-dimensional Vec, it takes up a lot of memory after initialization, so I want to release unused memory after some caculations.

Answer (score 2):

Truncating and shrinking is the best way. Releasing unused capacity is a distinct operation; there's no way around it. Rust doesn't do it automatically since you might be removing and then adding more elements.

Answer (score 1):

Rust docs https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees

> In general, Vec's allocation details are subtle enough that it is strongly recommended that you only free memory allocated by a Vec by creating a new Vec and dropping it.

I'm a Rust noob, but it seems to say that the solution would be:

```
let v = vec![v[0], v[1]];
```

(or `vec![&v[0], &v[1]]` if appropriate);

---

BTW. https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees also says:

> `push` and `insert` will never (re)allocate if the reported capacity is sufficient. `push` and `insert` will (re)allocate if `len()==capacity()`. That is, the reported capacity is completely accurate, and can be relied on. It can even be used to manually free the memory allocated by a `Vec` if desired.

I don't understand how to use this information :)

Comment: `Vec::resize` just calls `Vec::truncate` when the new length is equal/smaller than the current length. It doesn't shrink the vec to fit, so this method doesn't release unused memory.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I changed the answer completely...

Comment: The quote, "it is strongly recommended that you only free memory allocated by a Vec by creating a new Vec and dropping it," refers to deallocating the memory by hand, for example by freeing the pointer returned by [`into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts). The logic around when the pointer is valid is tricky so they don't recommend trying to free it yourself. This is all separate from calling `shrink_to_fit`, which is a fine way to reduce the allocation footprint.